# How safe is it to install chrome OS flex in a usb without affecting your main system?

Tags: operating-systems, bootable-media, google-chrome-os, liveusb, google-chrome-os-flex

So I have windows 7 (Ik, I have ancient PC), I have installed Kali Linux through a bootable USB before. I installed chrome OS using their official site and following the instructions but my whole PC just stuck at boot, even after unplugging the USB it just stuck there. I tried restarting but nope. Then I switched of my UPS and turned it on again, to my relief, it turned on.
I also have another laptop with similar specs, can I safely try to run chrome OS flex through USB in there?

Answer (score 0):

Should be safe as a house (assuming you don't initiate an install)...

How To Geek is your friend - https://www.howtogeek.com/786376/how-to-run-chrome-os-flex-on-your-pc-or-mac/

Comment: Do you have any idea what caused the PC not turning on?

Comment: No idea, I've never used it - I try to avoid the Google Machine! My best guesses are either your hardware doesn't meet the minimum system specs, and/or it's a Chrome OS Flex bug (remembering it's still experimental), and/or it's a mix of the two issues (i.e. some sort of hardware incompatibility). My 2c, stick with GNU/Linux...

Comment: I see.. I am probably gonna install once it's stable